# ScriptEngineManager get last successful line

Tags: javascript, nashorn, scriptengine

I am using ScriptEngineManager in my grails application to execute javascript code.

When I execute this javascript:

```
var x = new java.util.ArrayList([1, 2, 3]) 
log(x[55])
```

With this code:

```
try {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript")
    return engine.eval(javascript)
} catch (ScriptException jsEx) {
    // Exception is added in outer function to the log
    throw new JavascriptException(jsEx.getMessage(), jsEx)
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new JavascriptException("UNEXPECTED Exception in invokeJavaScript " + e.getMessage(), e)
}
```

I get a `java.lang.IndexOutOufBoundsException`in the Excpetion e. This is okay, but I want to know which line in the javascript the error occured. 
Is there a possibility to get the last successful line from javascript code?

Comment: Maybe there is an option for log every line that was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. I parse the stacktrace of the exception so I get the line number:

```
//this method gives me the stacktrace as string
String trace = helperService.stacktraceToString(e)
String line = ""
trace.eachLine {
    if (it.contains("<eval>")) {
        line = " at line " + it.substring(it.lastIndexOf("<eval>:"), it.length() -1).replace("<eval>:", "")
    }
}
```